# Composer error when trying to upgrade from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I followed the instructions on the official Laravel doc site. So here is my composer file. I changed the `symfony/css-selector` and `symfony/dom-crawler` versions to `3.1` but still get this error:

> Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.0, v2.7.9].
>   - laravel/framework v5.3.0 requires symfony/console 3.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2,
>   v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9].
>   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.9|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
>   - Installation request for kzykhys/ciconia ~1.0.0 -> satisfiable by kzykhys/ciconia[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "stevebauman/location": "1.3.*",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
    "kzykhys/ciconia": "~1.0.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.1",
    "cornford/googlmapper": "2.*",
    "likey/wiqi": "dev-master",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.7.0",
    "nicolaslopezj/searchable": "1.*",
    "algolia/algoliasearch-laravel": "^1.3",
    "bcdh/exist-db-rest-client": "^1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.2",
    "artesaos/seotools": "^0.10.0",
    "htmlmin/htmlmin": "^5.6",
    "contentful/contentful": "2.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
    "oriceon/oauth-5-laravel": "dev-master",
    "xethron/migrations-generator": "dev-l5",
    "way/generators": "dev-master"
  },
```

I get this error when I try to run `composer update --no-scripts`

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
```

....

```
install symfony/console v2.8.44|install symfony/console v2.8.45
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, v5.3.28, v5.3.29, v5.3.3, v5.3.30, v5.3.31, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.1|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.2|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.3|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.4|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.5|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.6|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.7|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.8|install kzykhys/ciconia v1.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't update is because you have package named `kzykhys/ciconia` if you look inside the [composer.json](https://github.com/kzykhys/Ciconia/blob/master/composer.json#L21) of it you will notice the line that requires this package to have `"symfony/console":">=2.3,<2.5-dev"` with conflicts with the `laravel/framework` requirements because it requires "symfony/console": "3.1.*""

```
|                           | kzykhys/ciconia | laravel/framework |
|---------------------------|-----------------|-------------------|
| `symfony/console` version | >=2.3,<2.5-dev  | 3.1.*             |
```